# Как работает рекурсия?

Tags: c++, рекурсия

```
int func(int n)
 {
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return func(n - 1) + 2;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    
    int n, d;

    cout << "Який член прогресії за рахунком ? - ";
    //cin >> n;
    
    d = func(4);

    if (d <= 21)
    {
        cout << d << endl;;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Как тут работает рекурсия? Значение n меняется от 4 до 1, как потом работает алгоритм?
Нужно найти n-ый член последовательности 1, 3, 5 ... 21 В примере 4-ый
спасибо

Comment: Допустим, 4 член последовательнсти = 7, как функция считает, что получается 7? Этого не пойму. То есть у нас последнее значение n = 1, ф-ия считает член прогрессии, какой алгоритм?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вызывается func(4) в которой идет проверка не единица ли в параметре, если нет, то вызывается func(3) + 2
2. Вызывается func(3) в которой идет проверка не единица ли в параметре, если нет, то вызывается func(2) + 2
3. Вызывается func(2) в которой идет проверка не единица ли в параметре, если нет, то вызывается func(1) + 2
4. Вызывается func(1) и так как в параметре единица, то она возвращается в п.3
5. Вместо func(1) + 2, вернулась 1 и мы получаем выражение 1 + 2, которое возвращается в п.2
6. Вместо func(2) + 2, вернулась 3 и мы получаем выражение 3 + 2, которое возвращается в п.1
7. Вместо func(3) + 2, вернулась 5 и мы получаем выражение 5 + 2, которое возвращается как результат 7.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @MaxKapko как отвтет пометьте)